# Multiple Months DayPilotMonth Lite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, daypilot

I am displaying a monthly DayPiolot Calendar on a mobile page, is there a way to display 3 months instead of only 1?

```
@Html.DayPilotMonth("dp", new DayPilotMonthConfig
 {
   BackendUrl = Url.Content("~/Home/Backend"),
   CssOnly = true,
   Theme = "month_green",
  })
```